# Angular 2 Dynamic Form Working on Plunker, but not on System

Tags: forms, data-binding, angular, typescript, angular2-forms

I'm trying to implement Custom Dynamic Forms in Angular 2. I've added functionalities like Delete and Cancel in addition to the Save already built.

I made all the changes in Plunker and now when i try to implement the same in local system, i'm getting errors.

Working Plunker Code: http://plnkr.co/edit/SL949g1hQQrnRUr1XXqt?p=preview

Error Messages: [image: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.]

Html code where the error is coming:

```
<div>
  <form [formGroup]="form">

    <div *ngFor="let question of questions" class="form-row">
      <label [attr.for]="question.key">{{question.label}}</label>

  <div [ngSwitch]="question.controlType">

    <input *ngSwitchCase="'textbox'" [formControlName]="question.key"
            [id]="question.key" [type]="question.type" [(ngModel)]="question.value">

    <select [id]="question.key" [(ngModel)]="question.value" *ngSwitchCase="'dropdown'" [formControlName]="question.key" >
      <option *ngFor="let opt of question.options" [ngValue]="opt.key" >{{opt.value}}</option>
    </select>

    <input *ngSwitchCase="'checkbox'"  [(ngModel)]="question.value"
            [id]="question.key" [type]="question.type" (change)="question.value = ck.checked" #ck [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">

  </div> 
  <div class="errorMessage" *ngIf="!form.controls[question.key].valid">{{question.label}} is required</div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
      <button type="submit" [disabled]="!form.valid" (click)="onSubmit()">Save</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="cancel()">Cancel</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="clear()">Clear</button>

    </div>
  </form>

  <div *ngIf="payLoad" class="form-row">
    <strong>Saved the following values</strong><br>{{payLoad}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same problem doing the Dynamic Forms tutorial adding a **moduleId** to each component. Ex:

```
 @Component({
        selector: 'dynamic-form',
        templateUrl: 'app/component/dynamic-form/dynamic-form.component.html',
        providers: [QuestionControlService],
        moduleId: 'dynamic-form'
    })
```

The problem is when you run angular2 rc5 in production, the bundled javascript can't insert your dependencies correctly, Another solution suggested is change the order in the declarations array in the NgModule, but the first was enough for my case.

`declarations: [ DynamicFormQuestionComponent , DynamicFormComponent, AppComponent]`